# Fork a GitHub repository to Azure DevOps, keep it partially synced with upstream

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-repos

There is a public repository in GitHub (let's call it repo **G**). I want to fork it into an Azure DevOps repository (let's call it repo **D**), which is easily done by using the "Import repository" feature in Azure DevOps.

Repo **G** contains some files (let's call them **X** files) that I will never modify myself. These files are regularly updated in the repo **G** and I want my repo **D** to get these changes.

Repo **G** also contains other files that I will be modifying (let's call them **Y** files). Changes to these files will be maintained in my repository **D** and they will never get pushed to the upstream repo **G**.

Obviously, people will also modify **Y** files in the upstream repo **G** but I am not interested in these changes.

How do I get latest changes to **X** files while ignoring changes to **Y** files?

Comment: Hi,
Have you handled it ? 
I have found such article: 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/import-git-repository?view=azure-devops#can-i-import-updates-if-the-source-changes-later

but I wonder if there is a way to do it without typing those commands manually.
So I think about something like this:
- import repository G (master) to D (submodule),
- make branch (mine) and change Y files,
- from time to time sync D (submodule) with G (master),
- fix conflicts (override X files, skip/manually adjust Y files)
- of course D is reffered by my mine project

Comment: thought about submodules too but never got to implement this. ended up ignoring Y files altogether and creating custom versions of them with prefixed filenames so that no conflicts occur.